# inline-block div overflowing when divs inside have padding or magins

Tags: css, html

Take a look at the following JSBin: http://jsbin.com/iheNOvo/3/edit

Here is the code also:

```
<html>
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
        #container {
            display: inline-block;
            width: 50%;
            height: 20%;
        }

        #elem1 {
            background-color: green;
            width: 50%;
            height: 100%;
            float: left;
            padding-right: 2%;
        }

        #elem2 {
            background-color: yellow;
            width: 50%;
            height: 100%;
            float: left;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<div id="container">
    <div id="elem1"></div>
    <div id="elem2"></div>
</div>
```

Problem is that the yellow div goes on to the next line because I added a padding to the first div. I am hoping that the container is able to wrap around whatever is inside it, but this doesn't seem to be working. Any thoughts on how I can achieve what I need?

Answer (score 1):

There is a little hack where you can add `box-sizing:border-box`, therefore the padding doesn't effect the width of the element.

[**jsbin demo**](http://jsbin.com/iheNOvo/4/edit)

```
#elem1 {
    box-sizing:border-box
}
```

Adding this, will cause both `divs` to render on the same line, as you wanted.

---

If you want to avoid this, either change the width on the parent, or the child element itself.

```
#elem1 {
    width: 48%;
    padding-right: 2%;
}
```

[**jsbin demo**](http://jsbin.com/iheNOvo/10/edit)

Comment: Even though this is correct, this is not the way to fix this situation (imho). Changing the way things get calculated should always remain as close to default as possible :)

Comment: @Martijn I disagree. What do you mean by "close to default" as possible? There are many solutions to a problem, and in this case I think `box-sizing` is the simplest and most elegant method.

Comment: @Terry Thanks! Glad you agree.

Comment: @JoshC I agree, therefore the upvote ;) in addition, Martijn's solution involves using a mixed margin AND additional `<div>` as a wrapper, which I typically frown upon due to the risk of divitis (i.e. using unnecessary divs to wrap elements).

Comment: Thanks, but the first jsbin demo doesn't work. My problem still isn't solved, as I can't change the width's of the elements. I simply need a way for the containing div to wrap around in size of whatever is inside it. Thanks again.

Comment: @piepi The first solution works for me - tested on Chrome and FF

Comment: @JoshC I'm on Firefox too, no luck. You seem to have forgotten the semi-colon at the end, but that doesn't change anything either. I'm running firefox on linux, though that shouldn't matter. Will try to find out what the matter is.

Comment: So I added '-moz-box-sizing: border-box;' and it works. Weird. Also, I realize my question was actually not entirely correct. What I want is a white space between the two divs. So I'm actually looking for margin and padding. Padding on both boxes because text will be inside them, and a margin in between so that there is space between them. So sorry about the mistake.

Comment: Alright, this is more representative of what I am having trouble with: http://jsbin.com/ikiMUn/1/edit Please let me know if you can get them both onto the same line, maintaining the padding, and with the margin between the two. Thank you!

Comment: @piepi Can't you just remove `display:inline-block` ?

Comment: I can't because I have more stuff on the same line in another div beside the container element. If I remove 'display: inline-block' then the container div will take up the full 100% width.

Comment: @piepi It's not possible then.. you can do this with padding using `box-sizing`, however a margin won't work unless it is calculated into the width, which isn't specified.

Comment: @piepi You can place a transparent div between the two.. http://jsbin.com/ikiMUn/5/edit

Comment: Hmm that doesn't work. Notice you changed `inline-block` to `inline_block`. That makes the div 100% wide.

Answer (score 0):

Updating my complete answer, topic starter whats a margin between the both:

http://jsfiddle.net/8XKAR/2/

```
#elem1 {
    background-color: green;
    width: 48%; /* 2% less */
    height: 100%;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 2%; /* you want margin instead of padding */
}
```

Another solution would be making `#elem1` and `#elem2` with 49% so they both give 1%, that way the margin will be centered

A final option is the boxing-model, an option which I dont prefer when there is an easy alternative. This is my personal opinion, but in my experience i've needed that exactly once.

```
#elem1 {
    box-sizing:border-box;
    margin-right: 2%; /*padding instead of margin */

}
```

Comment: The problem with this solution is that the padding is no longer fluid. In addition, you are wrapping the element with an unnecessary `<div>` that serves no semantic purpose.

Comment: I tried your second solution (I can't change size of divs) and it doesn't work. The  margin isn't showing, unfortunately.

Comment: I've added a fiddle, it does what it should :)

Comment: @Terry, I agree with you for this example. However, as soon as he add html to this, like a paragraph, the div in the css can be replace to make the P have a margin-right. 

I prefer my option 1 method over this though

Comment: Hmm, then I may be misunderstanding. There is no border between the green and yellow divs, unless I am mistaken. I need the white space in between.

Comment: ah, that wasnt what you where asking, 1 moment

Comment: I realized this now too, sincerest apologies.

Comment: I;ve changed my answer

Comment: Alright, this is more representative of what I am having trouble with: http://jsbin.com/ikiMUn/1/edit Please let me know if you can get them both onto the same line, maintaining the padding, and with the margin between the two. Thank you!

Comment: Exact same problem. width you want is like this: width=(width-margin-padding). In you case width =50-2-2-2 (padding both sides and margin). This is all very basic, try to read a bit about the boxmodel first

Comment: I know the box model quite well, I think. The problem is that if I do it your way, then the design won't be fluid. Since the font-size doesn't change, defining all the other parameters in terms of percents doesn't work because I can't calculate the exact size of the two inner divs. The box model would only work here if I could define a size for the outer container. But I can't do that, I need it to wrap whatever is inside and adjust its width accordingly. I don't know if that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

if you add a padding, you need to shrink your div to have 100%.

```
#elem1 {
    background-color: green;
    width: 48%;
    height: 100%;
    float: left;
    padding-right: 2%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

link: http://jsbin.com/iheNOvo/7/edit

```
#elem1 {
        width: 48%;
        padding-right: 2%;
}
```